# How to return optional debug information from a method?

Tags: c++, oop, debugging, fuzzy-comparison

Lets say I have a static method which compares two objects for a close match and returns some confidence level [0,1].

```
class Foo
{
  ...
  static double Compare(const Foo& foo1, const Foo& foo2);
  ...
};
```

Now I need to return additional debug information containing comparison details depending on a setting in the configuration.
Since this debug information won't be used at production, but only in testing/debugging purposes I was wondering what is the appropriate way to implement it.

I see at least three options:

1: Create an additional class CompareResult and store confidence + optional info there. Don't populate the optional info if you don't need to.

```
class CompareResult
{
  ...
private:
  double confidence_;
  CompareOptionalInfo compare_optional_info_;
  ...
};

...

static CompareResult Compare(const Foo& foo1, const Foo& foo2);
```

It seems to be the cleanest one, but I'm not sure if I should combine return result with an optional info.

2: Use output variable (this way we won't need to create an additional class, but our method signature will grow a bit)

```
static double Compare(const Foo& foo1, const Foo& foo2, CompareOptionalInfo* out_compare_info = nullptr);
```

3: Separate compare method with optional-info retrieval method.

```
static double Compare(const Foo& foo1, const Foo& foo2);
static CompareOptionalInfo GetCompareOptionalInfo();
```

This option would probably require to store this optional-info between the method invocations and shift from static compare method to the instance compare method.
But again, I'm not sure if it is appropriate or not.

From your experience, what is the appropriate way in OOP world to return optional information (which will be mostly used only in debug mode) from a method?

Comment: Do you plan to use a debugger or to only print the additional information in debug mode? If you want to use gdb and use commands like `call Foo::compare(foo1, foo2)` you will not be able to ask the `compare_optional_info_` of option 1.

Comment: Are you intending to build your production code in debug mode to test, or are you using a separate test program?

Comment: This is going to be an opinions based question (not really on topic). I would generally want to unit test my functions as "black boxes" that they follow a spec and only care what happens inside (from dbug perspective) if they fail. If there is something in there you really want to unit test then perhaps you could put that into its own function that is amenable to testing (option 1 or 2) and test that function separately rather than compromise the `API` with testing details. Another possibility is *conditionally compile* logging information in the function.

Comment: @Galik It's not an opinion based questions: it's not a question of style or taste here. Objective arguments can be provided to support an answer.

Comment: @Frank I plan to receive this optional information and use it to draw graphs (in analysis purposes). The caller program will use this optional information to draw graph and save it to disk.

Comment: @Peter We have a separate test program which invokes the methods of the library and depending on a configuration bit (e.g., debug-level) you are able to return some optional information for further using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 3** is not a good idea at all : having functions depending on static data is not practical and could become even be a source of bugs in the debugging.  Such a design is in addition not be thread safe ; what a pity it would be, to create such a restriction only for debugging purpose !

Examples of problems:

```
double closest = std::max (Foo::compare (x, y), Foo::compare (y,z));   
clog << Foo::GetCompareOptionalInfo();  // undefined which info since order of eval
                                        // of function parameter is not guaranteed

double d = Foo::compare (x, y); 
DoSomething();                    // what if this one does an unexpected  compare ? 
clog << Foo::GetCompareOptionalInfo();
```

---

**Option 2** is a viable solution, but it's not very convenient:  it forces you to create info objects, pass them by address etc:

```
Foo::OptionalCompareInfo o1,o2;    // cumbersome 
double closest = std::max (Foo::compare (x, y, &o1), Foo::compare (y,z, &o2));
```

In addition, you would create these optional infos and pass the extra argument in production as well, even if you no longer update the info there (unless you put a lot of extra conditional compilation) !

---

**Option 1** is excellent ! Go for it ! It really takes benefit of the OOP paradigm and uses a clean design.  It's practical to use and don't impose constraints on your code to use it.

All you need is to provide some (implicit) conversion function to use your  `CompareResult` almost as if it were a `double`:

```
class CompareResult
{
public:
  CompareResult(double d=0.0) : confidence_(d) {}; 
  operator double() { return confidence_; }
  operator bool() { return confidence_>0.5; }   
private:
  double confidence_;
  CompareOptionalInfo compare_optional_info_;
};
```

[**online demo**](http://ideone.com/XngYh9)

Your production code would be unaffected by the debugging information.  And you could in your debugging ALWAYS trace back the explanation of any given comparison result, at least if you store it:

Example:

```
auto result = Foo::compare (x, y)
if (result) ... // uses automatically the conversion

auto closest = std::max (Foo::compare (x, y), Foo::compare (y,z));
// here you not only know the closest match but could explain it ! 

vector<CompareResult> v;  
... // populate the vector with 10 000 comparison results
auto r = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());  
    // you could still explain the compare info for the largest value 
    // if you're interested in the details of this single value
    // how would you do this with option 3 or option 2 ?
```

Ok, for the very last one to work you'd also need a comparison operator for your additional class.  But that's one line of code more (see the online demo) ;-)

Finally, it could turn out that your "optional debug info" could prove to be more useful than expected, for example to provide the user additional explanations upon request.   All you need to do then, would be to remove the conditional `#ifdef DEBUG` surrounding the calculation of the optional info.

Comment: Thread locals makes it thread safe.  A queue of buffer or the like of debug infos means handling multiple acceptable; in the limit, this becomes logging.

Comment: @Yakk your are of course completely right if OP uses GCC>=4.8 or MSVC>=2015.  Queue buffer is indeed possible. But in the example of the function call with several compares in different parameters, you'd still not know in which order they are stored in the queue.  Therefore the question: why invest in making option 3 acceptable when option 1 is already a very good alternative ?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I like the idea to turn "optional debug info" into additional explanations upon request and I will definitely follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second option for its compatibility with debuggers.

In the debug mode, you can add an additional static member. You should take care of the linker that should not suppress it.

```
class Foo
{
  private:
#ifndef NDEBUG
  CompareOptionalInfo debug_out_compare_info_;
#endif

  ...
  static double Compare(const Foo& foo1, const Foo& foo2,
         CompareOptionalInfo* out_compare_info = nullptr);
  ...
};

#ifndef NDEBUG
CompareOptionalInfo Foo::debug_out_compare_info_;
#endif
```

In gdb, at any breakpoint, you can use:

```
call Foo::Compare(foo1, foo2, &Foo::debug_out_compare_info_);
print Foo::debug_out_compare_info_. ...
```

Comment: You are missing some NDEBUGs I think.

Comment: If I understand well, your idea is to use in the using code only two arguments (third defaulted to null), and use the third argument only in the debugger session.  That's ok for ad-hoc analysis.  However, if in the debug you would also want to do some logging, you' d need to create the `CompareOptionalInfo` variables and pass their address.  These would then remain in production unless you'd add a lot of conditional compilation...

Comment: @Christophe All depends if you want to use logging in production. The `CompareOptionalInfo` could be also hidden in you log class. I think you can hide the conditional compilations in some key classes/methods. Moreover, in the debugger you can ask for `Compare` on elements that have not been compared in the code or compared in the past/future.

Comment: @Yakk In production code, `debug_out_compare_info_` should not appear and `out_compare_info` is likely to be always `nullptr`. Yes if the compiler has not this contextual information, it wouldn't optimize the `Compare` method. You can add `#ifndef NDEBUG` around the third argument of `Compare`, but it will also prevent you from logging in production code. Maybe some `NDEBUG` are missing from external code - it depends on the concrete calls to `Compare`.

Comment: @Frank I'd like to keep capability to set the debug-level to some value without recompilation and receive this optional information back.